# Downvote button is non-responsive for answers in the iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I have some problems downvoting answers using the Stack Exchange iOS app.

When I tap the *downvote* arrow for the first time, nothing happens. When I tap it again for the second time, nothing happens again. Finally, I start tapping the *downvote* button furiously and then the downvote takes effect.

Why is it so hard to downvote an answer using the iOS app? Upvotes are fast and easy to cast as well as downvotes for the questions.

**Note:** This behavior appears on iPhone 6+ *every time* I try to downvote.

**Edit:** When I try to downvote a self-posted answer, the *downvote* arrow works, increasing the number of downvotes for a moment, then a notification about impossibility to downvote self-posted answers appears.

---

Am I the only victim of this bug? Could you please fix it?

Comment: @BlueMoon, certainly not. I don't downvote very often _mainly because of this bug_ (or is it a feature?)

Comment: shouldn't this be tagged bug?

Comment: @rene, yes, it should. I updated the question.

Comment: If upvoting works I expect a lot of users hope this never gets fixed...

Comment: Why was this closed? It's clear enough what he's asking, although there seems to be a problem reproducing the issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus, please vote to reopen then.

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: @Cerbrus, I've just noticed it. Thank you.

Comment: If it's truly fixed, the moderators can use the meta tag [meta-tag:status-completed] to mark it as fixed.

Comment: @Makoto, OK, I'll wait for it. It seems to work for me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue was fixed in 1.3.1.  Basically the score view, which holds the up/down/score views but not accept or bounty, was constrained to 88pt tall despite having content around 110pt tall.  Because the view had `clipsToBounds = NO`, the button was visible but only the top 20pt were tappable, well under Apple's 44pt guideline.

Now the view doesn't have a size constraint but has its bottom edge constrained to be greater than or equal to the bottom edge of the down vote button with high vertical hugging.